# Is there already a Conditional Zip function in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, linq-to-objects, system.reactive

Is there already a function in C# that can perform a "Conditional Zip"?

I.e.

Is there a function that allows different length inputs and takes a predicate which determines when to increment the smaller sources enumerator, such that all elements in the larger source are seen?

As a contrived example, lets assume we have an enumerable of prime numbers and an enumerable of integers (both sorted ascending). We want to produce a new enumerable that holds the prime and all integers since the previous prime.

```
{2, 3, 5, 7, 11}

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,}

{2, [1]}, {3,[]}, {5, [4]}, {7, [6]}, {11, [8,9,10]}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, but also niche enough that I doubt you will find a ready-made implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, IEnumerable<T2>>> ConditionalZip<T1, T2>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> src1,
    IEnumerable<T2> src2,
    Func<T1, T2, bool> check)
{
    var list = new List<T2>();
    using(var enumerator = src2.GetEnumerator())
    {
        foreach(var item1 in src1)
        {
            while(enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var pickedItem = enumerator.Current;
                if(check(item1, pickedItem))
                {
                    list.Add(pickedItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            var items = list.ToArray();
            list.Clear();
            yield return new Tuple<T1, IEnumerable<T2>>(item1, items);
        }
    }
}
```

It guarantees that both enumerations will be enumerated only once.

Usage:

```
var src1 = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
var src2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 11);
Func<int, int, bool> predicate = (i1, i2) => i1 > i2;
var result = src1.ConditionalZip(src2, predicate);
```

Comment: This is valid and compared to my answer that seems like O(n) (n: src2.Count()), so better.

Comment: @EvrenKuzucuoglu Although `.ToArray();` is an O(n) operation and so is `.Clear()`.

Comment: I took this idea and the source of Zip and made a solution. Marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

That's a nice one. I don't think you'll find a ready-made function directly within .net but if the operation you want is a standard action in maths I'm sure there's a library somewhere that does it. If you wanted to do it yourself, though, you could use group by. In this particular scenario:

```
var primes = new List<int> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11};
var numbers = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

var groups =
    from number in numbers
    group number by primes.First(prime => prime >= number) into gnumber
    select new {
        prime = gnumber.Key,
        numbers = gnumber.Where(n => n != gnumber.Key)
    };
```

That seems like a simple enough solution. It will create an enumerable of an anonoymous type with two members in it.
You can transform it into a dictionary:

```
var dict = groups.ToDictionary(g => g.prime, g=> g.numbers);
```

Edit: primes has to be ordered for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that! However I need something like Zip which enumerates only once. I can't guarantee the enumerables can be enumerated more than once.

Comment: Indeed in this case the algorithm is something like O(n*p) so instinctively I would say not optimal. If you knew a specific optimal algorithm though there's no reason why you should not be able to implement it with standard loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I went with (ugly implementation) but enumerates the enumerables only once.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Merges two sequences by using the specified predicate function to determine when to iterate the second enumerbale.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1"/> that contains merged elements of two input sequences.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="larger">The first sequence to merge.</param><param name="smaller">The second sequence to merge.</param>
    /// <param name="resultSelector">A function that specifies how to merge the elements from the two sequences (a flag is passed into the dunction to notify when elements of the second source are exhausted.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="TFirst">The type of the elements of the first input sequence.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TSecond">The type of the elements of the second input sequence.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the elements of the result sequence.</typeparam>
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> ConditionalZip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> larger, IEnumerable<TSecond> smaller, Func<TFirst, TSecond, bool> predicate, Func<TFirst, TSecond, bool, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        if (larger == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("larger");
        if (smaller == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("smaller");
        if (resultSelector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("resultSelector");
        else
            return ConditionalZipIterator(larger, smaller, predicate, resultSelector);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TResult> ConditionalZipIterator<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, bool> predicate, Func<TFirst, TSecond, bool, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TFirst> enumerator1 = first.GetEnumerator())
        {
            using (IEnumerator<TSecond> enumerator2 = second.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!enumerator2.MoveNext())
                {
                    secondIsFinished = true;
                }
                currentSecond = secondIsFinished ? default(TSecond) : enumerator2.Current;

                while (enumerator1.MoveNext())
                {

                    while (!secondIsFinished && !predicate(enumerator1.Current, currentSecond))
                    {
                        if (!enumerator2.MoveNext())
                        {
                            secondIsFinished = true;
                        }
                        currentSecond = secondIsFinished ? default(TSecond) : enumerator2.Current;
                    }


                    yield return resultSelector(enumerator1.Current, currentSecond, secondIsFinished);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The usuage

> var primes = new int[] {2, 3, 5, 7, 11}.ThrowIfEnumeratedMoreThan(1);
>   var ints = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ThrowIfEnumeratedMoreThan(1);

```
        var results = ints.ConditionalZip(primes, (i, prime) => i <= prime, (i, prime, isEmpty) => new {i, prime, wasMatched=!isEmpty})
            .Where(x => x.wasMatched)
            .GroupBy(x => x.prime)
            .Select(x => new {Prime = x.Key, Values = x.Where(n => n.i != n.prime).Select(n=>n.i).ToArray()})
            .ToArray();
```